# I have problem with my react js form. It says that "Form(...): Nothing was returned from render. why?

Tags: reactjs

Can you guys help me with my code? I tried to create a simple form using ReactJS that display an input of username and there is a button when click the button, it will alert the user input.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TopbarForm title="Form"></TopbarForm>
      <br></br>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{marginleft:'12', marginright:'12'}}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please share few more information / code such as state variable, methods

Comment: May be the problem lies in TopbarForm

Comment: problem is your `TopbarForm`, please post `TopbarForm` code

Comment: hmm i just remove it and it would still remain the same error. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

If we exclude `<TopbarForm title="Form"></TopbarForm>` this code actually works.
Except you should change: `style={{ marginLeft: "12px", marginRight: "12px" }}`

Comment: i just remove the <TopbarForm> and still remain the same. What should I do?

Comment: render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <br></br>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }